# How do I install ubuntu over earlier ubuntu?

Tags: installation, upgrade, updates, update-manager

My upgrade manager is broken on 10.04.  I have been stuck on 10.04.  My upgrade manager won't fetch something that it needs to and fails to upgrade.  I have put the install iso on a thumb drive and push f12 to boot from usb memory but all i get is a blinking cursor.  How do I install new ubuntu over 10.04?

It says could be network problem but thunderbird pidgin and firefox all work.

Comment: is there a specific error you are getting when you try to update it? if we know what error then we might be able to help you fix it and thus help you upgrade....

Answer (score 0):

Mere copying iso to the thumb drive will not make it a bootable disk. Please follow the steps given here

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick